# Saving reference to service in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, service, android-orientation

On a button click a service is started, and stopped when another button is clicked.

On rotation I have saved the state of the buttons, enabled/disabled.

Now I need to save reference to the service running in the background, so that it can still be stopped when the second button is clicked. Currently it has a null pointer exception, as once the activity is broken down and recreated the reference to the Intent from the first button click no longer exists.

Any ideas on how to pass this information over using onSaveInstanceState?

Answer (score 0):

I simply removed the intent to another class and start/stopped it through there.